# Connecting multiple microcontrollers to a CAN bus

Tags: microcontroller, can, network

I want to set up a network of microcontroller communicating via the CAN protocol. How do I go about the wiring? Do I directly connect all the RX/TX wires together; will it work and be reliable? Or is there a specific/better way to build a CAN bus?

Comment: Downvoted because no research has been done on the subject.

Comment: @Koundinya why don't you draw up a schematic with the tool of an example of how you think the CAN bus should be constructed. We can't check what your thinking if you don't provide enough information. A good question generates good answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fj74xh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There are no Rx/Tx on a CAN bus; there is CAN high and CAN Low.  You need to use a CAN Transceiver between the CAN bus and the micro's Rx and Tx signals. Devices should be connected to the bus with stubs as short as practical, and the bus must have a 120 ohm termination resistor at each end.